# Navigation Drawer with header in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Using the help of http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example.html

I managed to get my navigation drawer working. I have also added a header to my Drawer. In my header, I have a Imageview, two TextView

The data is showing up properly, but for some reason the UI is different in each phone. The image is getting cut or the background image is showing up big.

Here is the screen shot of Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 5 I have tested:

[image] **Nexus 5**

[image]

**Galaxy Nexus**

Here is the header XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearTotalLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundforprofile"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutforImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profilepic" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutforText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:layout_weight=".70"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Joe David"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="JoeDavidJoeDavi@joedavidjoedavid.com"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can somebody help me fix this issue?

Thanks!

**Update**

As per advice from @Rohan Pawar and @westito I change the layout to relative The ImageView is not getting cut and text is coming out properly, but the background image is still a difference in Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 5. Please see my screenshot below.

[image: Galaxy Nexus Screen]

**Galaxy Nexus**

[image: Nexus 5 Screen]

**Nexus 5**

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearTotalLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundforprofile"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profilepic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageforprofile"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="Dushyant Prabhu"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textforprofile"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageforprofile"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="developer@sybershocknetworks.com"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try using relative layout

Comment: @RohanPawar: I tried the Relative Layout the text format is perfect now, but the background image is different in each phone. I even changed the height of relative layout I don't see any difference? Please check my updated question

Comment: what is the resolution of your background image ?

Comment: @RohanPawar: 1600 * 900. When the width is coming up properly why not the height?

Comment: try android:layout_height="match_parent" to main layout

Comment: @RohanPawar : It comes huge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59324/discussion-between-rohan-pawar-and-thedevman).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your layout. Instead of LinearLayouts, try using RelativeLayout. It is more efficient for this layout.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView id="@+id/image" />
    <TextView  layout_toRightOf="@+id/image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is a "pseudo" sample. You can position your TextView next to ImageView

Comment: I tried the Relative Layout the text format is perfect now, but the background image is different in each phone. I even changed the height of relative layout I don't see any difference? Please check my updated question

Answer (score 2):

@TheDevMan i have both devices Nexus 5 and Galaxy nexus, i have tested out your code works on both device perfectly

Samsung Galaxy Nexus = 720 x 1280 pixels, 4.65 inches (~316 ppi pixel density)

LG Nexus 5= 1080 x 1920 pixels, 4.95 inches (~445 ppi pixel density)

but i dont have your background image to test

Comment: It is the Google+ default cover page for each profile user.

Answer (score 0):

try this for your header & customize it as you want it will work for sure

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_header"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/placeholder"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:text="Krunal Patel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="19dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your code, I couldn't add one more textview below nav_user_name?